# Custom typeface lays on top of original text

Tags: android, typeface

I use my own font from assets/fonts folder and sometimes when I start the app (not always), the original text and font is loaded and my own typeface is loaded on top of the original text. It's like my own font is applied to slow.

Is there something I can do to prevent this from happening. This is the code:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     // some code
     initializeControls();
}

private void initializeControls() {
    // TextViews
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    Typeface tfLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

    tvTimer = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);
    tvTimer.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to call the initializeControls() at onStart(); 
because it's at that point when you have the interface created and then you put your typeface and text. I hope I helped you :)

Comment: This is a fragment. Should I put it in `onCreateView` before `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, container, false);` instead?

Comment: After the inflate, before the view creation, or you'll get a null exception.

Comment: Yep this seems to work just fine. This is a hard thing to debug since it happends randomly. Thank for the help.